# Product agnostic book on Message Queues?

Tags: books, message-queue

Are there any recommendations for book(s) that are largely agnostic (with examples of MQ implementations is fine) on vendor but go to great details on the architecture, management, nomenclature, atomicity, durability, patterns, and logical deployments on Message Queue systems?

Surely there are enough shared concepts between MQ Series, MSMQ, SysV IPC (OK, that might be stretching it), RabbitMQ, &c &c?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/)? It's not exclusively on message queues, but on messaging systems.

> The book *[Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/eaipatterns.html)* provides a consistent vocabulary and visual notation to describe large-scale integration solutions across many implementation technologies. It also explores in detail the advantages and limitations of asynchronous messaging architectures. You will learn how to design code that connects an application to a messaging system, how to route messages to the proper destination and how to monitor the health of a messaging system. The patterns in the book are technology-agnostic and come to life with examples implemented in different messaging technologies, such as SOAP, JMS, MSMQ, .NET, TIBCO and other EAI Tools...

Comment: Will investigate.

Answer (score 3):

I think the book you are looking for would be a valuable resource but in my experience I've only ever seen books available as they apply to one vendor or another.  I've had a lot of experience with IBM MQ and a fair amount with MSMQ and have looked for references from time to time but have never come across what you are looking for.  I'll be interested to see if anyone else has a different experience.